# Spring RowMapper returns ArrayList for one result

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring Boot to build REST service which connects to Oracle DB. I'm allso using Spring JDBC.

I have a following code:

```
jdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_IN", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
jdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("P_OUT", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ClientMapper()));

MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("P_IN", "123");
Map out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
Client client = (Client) out.get("P_OUT");
```

Procedure returns just one result, but when I execute the code I get the following errror:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.test.model.Client
```

In a debug mode I can see that `out.get("P_OUT")`returns `ArrayList` with 10 objects, First one is my Client object and others are set to `null`.

I'm confused, what am I doing wrong and hove to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Procedure returns one result

How does Spring know that?  It needs to be able to cope with cursors that could return any number of rows.  To me it makes sense that `out.get("P_OUT")` returns a List.

> In a debug mode I can see that `out.get("P_OUT")` returns `ArrayList` with 10 objects

I suspect that when you are seeing the 10 objects you are looking at the internal array used by the `ArrayList`.  Try printing out the `size()` of the `ArrayList`.  I would expect this to print out `1`.

The `ArrayList` class may keep spare space on the end of its internal array to allow it to add an element quickly.  It will also keep track of how many elements in the array are actually used.

So, in short, you need to do the following:

```
List<Client> clients = (List<Client>) out.get("P_OUT");
Client client = clients.get(0);
```

You may also want to consider adding some error-handling in the situation that the cursor should, for whatever reason, return no data.  The cast to `List<Client>` may also appear as a warning in your IDE: a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation should address that.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! I also realized that it makes perfect sense that it returns a List. Maybe we should consider procedures out parameter, because we know that it should return one and only one result always, and out parameter should not be a cursor.